# How to create C# model when JSON properties are unknown

Tags: c#, model

I get this result set from an API call. `"data":` returns an object containing properties named using a number generator for `taskID` assignment (example: `"6688288":` and `"6798986":`)

The `"6688288":` property name is generated by the host system and is unknown at each API request.

```
{
    "result": true,
    "data": {
        "6688288": {  <--- cannot model this property - It is unknown at each API request
            "taskId": 6688288,
            "owner": "Vader",
        },
        "6798986": {
            "taskId": 6798986,
            "owner": "Palpatine",
        },
        "6688269": {
            "taskId": 6688269,
            "owner": "Tarkin"
        }
    }
}
```

I have not been able to create a model for this situation in C# because you cannot predict what `taskId` numbers will be returned.

```
public class Root
{
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    // Here is where the model breaks down, these properties are unknown at each json request.
    
    [JsonProperty("6688288")]
    public _6688288 _6688288 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6798986")]
    public _6798986 _6798986 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6688269")]
    public _6688269 _6688269 { get; set; }
}

public class _6688288 //Unknown
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
}

public class _6798986 //Unknown
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
}

public class _6688269 //Unknown
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to create a list of tasks using this model in the most efficient manner possible.

```
public class myTask
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
}
```

It would have been easy if the API developers had simply returned `"data": [ { "taskId": "6688288" }, { "taskId": "6798986" }, { "taskId": "6688269" } ]`,
but they didn't.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would prefer to use C# models to directly deserialize the full json.  But if forced to break it into pieces of the json, my preference is `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, myTask> data { get; set; }` - check out the duplicates.